# sed command to replace / with ; only for condition

Tags: sed

Please tell me how to replace `/` with `;` in this:

```
ASAL
/*
 * VIEW: VINAME1 
 */
Create view viewname
/
test
```

I need to convert only the lone `/`, so the output should be like this:

```
ASAL
/*
 * VIEW: VINAME1 
 */
Create view viewname
;
test
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a `/` between the start and the end of the line. As a regex that's `^/$`:

```
 sed 's|^/$|;|' your_file
```

Comment: Maybe you should allow whitespace around the slash?

Comment: How to add space and tab also in this

Comment: @asalthangam I cover whitespace in my answer. BTW, please accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the check mark on the left side. (Not saying it's mine, but it's definitely mine :-P )

Answer (score 2):

This identifies the slash as being the only character in the line:

```
sed 's.^/$.;.g'
```

Caret indicates start of line, dollar indicates end of line.

Edit: To allow for whitespace before and after the slash, and delete it:

```
sed -r 's.^(\s)?/(\s)?$.;.'
```

Edit 2: To allow for whitespace and not delete it:

```
sed -r '/^(\s)?\/(\s)?$/ s./.;.'
```